# SQL Server trigger: How to break space delimited text into list for email

Tags: sql-server

I have the following trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[movedtoFG]
ON [dbo].[Final_Yld]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @body += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + RTRIM(Name)+' moved the following to Finished Goods' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10)+  'Shop Order:  '+ RTRIM (SO)+ CHAR(10)+ 'Part Number:   '  + RTRIM (PartNO) + CHAR(10) +'Quantity:   ' + RTRIM (QtyPass)+ CHAR(10) +  'Serial Numbers:  '+ CHAR(13) +RTRIM (SerialNO)
    FROM inserted;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @recipients = 'customerservice@touchstn.com;', 
          @profile_name = 'TS-ERP MAIL',
          @subject = 'Ready To Ship', 
          @body = @body;
    END
END
```

Which nicely yields this email body:

```
Andre moved the following to Finished Goods

Shop Order:  50020223

Part Number:   FPM1237

Quantity:   4

Serial Numbers:  

032321.15-9062-100.16 032321.15-9062-100.17 032321.15-9062-100.18 032321.15-9062-100.19
```

I would like it to format with the SerialNO column in a list like this:

```
Serial Numbers: 
  
032321.15-9062-100.16 
032321.15-9062-100.17
032321.15-9062-100.18
032321.15-9062-100.19
```

The column is always space delimited but string lengths can vary (sometimes contains text/etc)

Comment: Why not simply replace the space with a CRLF  ... replace(SerialNO,' ',CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))

Comment: Please do some research about sending emails from a trigger. This is not a good idea.

Comment: Database Mail uses an intermediate Service Broker queue to store-and-forward the mail.  The trigger simply inserts a row (message) into a table (queue), and a background process actually sends the mail.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail?view=sql-server-ver15#scalability